# Adjust iPhone's volume via Apple Watch when content being played isn't mine

Tags: ios, swift, audio, apple-watch, volume

Suppose I'm watching a YouTube video on my iPhone. To adjust the volume using my Apple Watch, I turn the crown, and some apps provide a simple interface for Watch with volume sliders, rewind options, and so on.

However, I would like to develop an app, running on my watch, that programmatically adjusts my phone's volume regardless of where or what the content being played is. For example, every minute, I generate a random number and my phone's volume is set to that value via my watch. Whether I'm watching Netflix or playing music through Apple Music, I'd like that change to take effect.

There are a few examples here and on other forums that deal with I) Changing the iPhone's volume when the content isn't mine through the iPhone itself and II) Changing the iPhone's volume when the content is mine through the watch, but nothing that combines the two.

Would you please share your thoughts on how I would go about doing it?

Thank you!